# Align Bokeh DataTable column widths

Tags: bokeh

I have a bokeh DataTable

[image]

As you can see, the columns are all the same width.  This results in a fair amount of whitespace and some clipping.  Is there a way that I can specify default column widths?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TableColumn (which composes a DataTable) has a `width` attr that can be set:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.tables.html#bokeh.models.widgets.tables.TableColumn